# Groupby functionality on multiple fields in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement where I need to groupby status_value as per regions and regions as per given date. For the same I have written a query and it is not exactly working in the ES. It would be a great help, if someone look into this and provide me with the solution.

Note: I would like to get the result for the last day (i.e. previous day).

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "UsagePoint_Asset_lifecycle_installationDate": "2014-07-13T16:55:00.0-07:00"
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "aggs" : {
        "product" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "UsagePoint_ServiceLocation_region"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "material" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "field" : "UsagePoint_status_value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

my sql query may be like below:

```
select count(status_value)
from products 
where date = "yesterday"
group by region , date
```

Please check below query is working, but I would like to get the values for a specific day or dates.

```
{
    "agg1": {
        "terms": {
           "field":"UsagePoint_Asset_lifecycle_installationDate"
        },
        "aggs" : {
        "product" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "UsagePoint_ServiceLocation_region"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "material" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "field" : "UsagePoint_status_value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work just fine , why do you feel its not giving right result ?

Comment: Between term filter on date field wont mostly work , but then i can only tell anything after seeing the mappings too

Comment: Actually, ES says there are some syntactical errors.. I need to get the details for a particular date or dates.. I have tried one more query.. Can you please check in the question and advice.. @Vineeth Mohan

Comment: First you need to define UsagePoint_Asset_lifecycle_installationDate as date in the mappings and then use range query.

Comment: Yeah, this is a date field in the mapping.. and I can filter the days on that field. Just wanted the result for previous day.. that too want to get the count of 'UsagePoint_status_value' per 'UsagePoint_ServiceLocation_region' for yesterday or a specific days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the group by info for yesterday , the following is a solution.
For any other custom dates , change the value in gte ( Greater than or equals to ) and lt ( Less than )

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "UsagePoint_Asset_lifecycle_installationDate": {
            "gte": "now-1d",
            "lt": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "UsagePoint_ServiceLocation_region"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "material": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "UsagePoint_status_value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, The above query is an exact match for my requirement. But, have a challenge that might be caused due to ES version. When I run this query in my ES, it throws the below error. Can you please check and help..

Comment: Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [work_orders][4]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [filtered] in [query]]